# SQLite Update Statement Is Not Working

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an update statement that I'm trying to execute:

```
String update_stock = "UPDATE " + table_name_ + " SET " + current_stock + " = " + current_stock + " - " + sub_stock + " where item_name = '" + item_name + "'";
    getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(update_stock, null);
```

I've checked the query in log  `Log.d("updatesss", update_stock);` which gave me:

`UPDATE APPLE_CHILLAM SET current_stock = current_stock - 1 where item_name = 'Double Apple'`

The value is not getting updated. What am I missing?
The datatype of the `current_stock` column is in int.

Comment: are you sure that there is a row with `item_name` `'Double Apple'`

Comment: why not doing with a ID? I mean where id = 'something'?

Comment: yes @VladMatvienko

Comment: its the same. There will be no duplicate @3iL

Comment: it is primary key @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: I recommend you run this query in some DB browser. I use DB browser for SQLite for such purposes.

Comment: Query executed successfully: UPDATE APPLE_CHILLAM SET current_stock = current_stock - 1 where item_name = 'Double Apple' (took 32ms, 1 rows affected)
@3iL

Comment: @TuhinSubhra I've posted a answer..have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `execSQL` instead of `rawQuery`:

```
execSQL("UPDATE " + table_name_ + " SET " + current_stock + " = " + current_stock - sub_stock + " where item_name = '" + item_name + "'");
```

**Difference between `execSql` and `rawQuery`**:

[execSql](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29)

Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.

> It has no means to return any data (such as the number of affected
>   rows). Instead, you're encouraged to use insert(String, String,
>   ContentValues), update(String, ContentValues, String, String[]), et
>   al, when possible.

[rawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29)

> Runs the provided SQL and returns a Cursor over the result set.

Comment: whats wrong with rawQuery. Your suggestion worked. Thanks @Godot

Comment: welocme @TuhinSubhra! I edited my answer, see this links and you would know about difference

Comment: well explained @Godot

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

database.execSQL("UPDATE " + table_name_ + " SET " + current_stock + " = " + current_stock + " - " + sub_stock + " where item_name = '" + item_name + "'");
```

Comment: Thanks. The only difference is **execSQL** . i dont understand why rawQuery didnt work

Comment: @TuhinSubhra Sloppy mistake!

Comment: @TuhinSubhra, rawQuery is generally used when you want to return any data like in SELECT statement. Good to keep this in mind in your future developments.